# Atribuir tipo a array em PHP

Tags: php, array, tipagem

Eu sei que PHP é uma linguagem fracamente tipada. Mas existe alguma forma alternativa de "tipar" um `array` em PHP?

Exemplo, eu consigo fazer isso abaixo para forçar receber numa função um tipo de dado específico.

```
function exemplo(Classe $valor){
    // meu código aqui ...
}
```

Porém, gostaria de saber como fazer algo parecido como se faz em Java (Veja abaixo) com listas.

```
List<String> array = new ArrayList<>;
```

Existe uma maneira de fazer isso em PHP?

Comment: Você quer assegurar que dentro da array haverão apenas valores de um tipo específico?

Comment: Sim. Por default o PHP trata-os como mixed. Queri definir um tipo X. @Cahe

Comment: Isso é so para melhorar o auto complete da IDE ou tem algo especial no seu código que precisa.

Comment: Na verdade é só mania por que uso isso no java.

Comment: Não diria que é só mania, faz sentido mas a linguagem não permite.

Comment: @bigown na sua opinião isso é um ponto fraco da linguagem ou simplesmente um característica inerente ao PHP que cabe a cada um a sua respectiva escolha de linguagem para seu projeto?

Comment: É bem opinião. Eu acho que é um ponto fraco e um ponto forte :) Nada é de todo bom e todo ruim. Em programação sempre falamos em *tradeoffs*. Sempre trocamos uma coisa pela outra. Fazemos escolhas de qual defeito queremos conviver já que nada é perfeito. Para granes bases de código manipuladas por grandes equipes em sistemas que são feitos para durar não ter tipos pode dificultar bastante. Mas também simplifica códigos em várias situações. Tá ficando longo, isto até daria uma boa pergunta (feita do jeito certo). Se ninguém postar nada nos próximos dias, eu faço.

Comment: Obrigado novamente e estou no aguardo para assistir o desenrolar da conversa. @bigown

Comment: Discussão não pode, só respostas objetivas (ou pelo meno menos [boas subjetivas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/486/101)) :)

Comment: Soou estanho, mas me expressei errado. Não quis dizer DISCUSSÃO no sentido agressivo. Na verdade, falei à respeito de debater o assunto e cada um apresentar seu ponto de vista.

Comment: E eu só brinquei, eu tinha entendido :) Mas mesmo debate não é permitido nests *site*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não é possível.

PHP era dinamicamente e fracamente tipada, no fundo nada tem tipo fixo. Todos os *arrays* do PHP aceitam que qualquer elemento tenha qualquer tipo. Pode misturar à vontade. É uma característica inerente deste tipo de linguagem. Não há sintaxe ou opção no compilador que possa forçar ou mesmo indicar que tipo de dados os elementos podem ter. Ou seja eles sempre serão *mixed* de acordo com a definição do PHP.

Já [Hack](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/hack.generics.php) que é uma evolução do PHP criado pelo Facebook permite *generics* e os "*arrays*" podem ser tipados. Apesar de ter como base o PHP, é outra linguagem.

É possível parcialmente em PHP desde a versão 7, e na 7.4 isto se torna mais forte, mas é feito de forma capenga porque ela tem o legado sem tipo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "Não é possível" nativamente :)

Comment: Como é possível?

Comment: Com alguma classe que implemente o ArrayAccess para simular um Array. Eu achei que o SplType fazia isso, mas ele só serve para os outros valores (que não o Array)

Comment: E como o compilador verificaria isto?

Comment: Não tem como mesmo, @bigown. No PHP, pra esses coisas funcionarem (e ainda nem é 100%) é só instalando extensões ou então [simulando um array tipado](https://github.com/wallacemaxters/types/tree/master/src/WallaceMaxters/Types) na base da gambiarra

Answer (score 1):

Isso também é algo que sempre me incomodou não saber os tipos de elementos que tenho dentro de um array.

A implementação que resolvi fazer foi extender a Classe **IteratorIterator** do PHP. Essa classe solicita que seja um injetado uma interface de Iterator e assim ela utiliza seus métodos pelo método mágico **__call**. O que foi feito foi criar um método de entrada para os elementos com o parâmetro tipado e inserir um outro método de entrada da classe ArrayIterator (offsetSet) como privado.

Então fiz esse código.

```
  
class TestArrayIterator extends IteratorIterator {

    private $arrayIterator;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->arrayIterator = new ArrayIterator();
        parent::__construct($this->arrayIterator);
    }

    public function append(IElement $element) {
        $this->offsetSet(null, $element);
    }

    private function offsetSet($key, IElement $element) {
        $this->arrayIterator->offsetSet($key, $element);
    }

}

interface IElement {

    public function getCodigo();
    public function getNome();

}

class Element implements IElement {

    private $codigo;
    private $nome;

    public function setCodigo($codigo) {
        $this->codigo = $codigo;
    }

    public function setNome($nome) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }

    public function getCodigo() {
        return $this->codigo;
    }

    public function getNome() {
        return $this->nome;
    }
}

$element = new Element();
$element->setCodigo(1);
$element->setNome('nome 1');

$element_1 = new Element();
$element_1->setCodigo(2);
$element_1->setNome('nome 2');


$testIterator = new TestArrayIterator();
$testIterator->append($element);
$testIterator->append($element_1);

foreach ($testIterator as $key => $element) {   
    echo $key . ' - ' . $element->getCodigo() . ' => ' . $element->getNome() . "\n";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade existe sim uma forma de tipar php apesar dele ser dinamicamente tipado. 
Da uma olhada neste link http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php

Para tipar php você deve fazer dessa forma:

```
settype($foo, "integer");
```

Assumindo assim que $foo é do tipo inteiro.
Como o amigo acima mencionou existe a hack language que trabalha com um "php" tipado, já realizei alguns testes na linguagem, porém não acho ainda madura o suficiente para abandonar o bom e velho php.